Why are so many of my questions neither answered nor upvoted?
Before I deleted my account, I posted several new questions over several months, many of which were neither answered nor upvoted. I wonder if there is something wrong with my questions.
I've never thought the topic of using cadence in writing to be widely disinteresting, rather, I thought that my unsuccessful use of it, my tendency to use archaic phrasing, and my lack of clarity were problematic. Regardless, no one is answering or upvoting my questions, although I have refrained from asking exactly the same question most of the time.
Why is this?

I will once again note that many of your unanswered and un-upvoted questions were self-deleted within 24 hours - and sometimes as quickly as 1 hour - before they actually had a chance to be upvoted or answered. This has never been one of the more active sites on the network, especially since we lost our old mod team and many of our most active users during the Monica controversy a while back, and not all users are awake or available at the same time. You simply cannot expect your questions to receive immediate attention here.

Okay. Thank you.

There may be four reasons why your questions don't get as much interaction as you hope for:
1   This site has only a handful of active users.
2   As F1Krazy has pointed out, you delete your questions before they can be answered.
3   You are disrespectful.
If you are the person I think you are (the user garbia), I'll repeat what I wrote as a comment under one of your questions on April 13, 2024:

According to your profile you have asked 77 questions of which 71 have received one or more answers, and yet you have accepted answers for only 4 of your questions. I have looked at some of your recent questions, and most have received answers that in my opinion fully answer your question, some have even received several acceptable answers. To me, the fact that you only very rarely accept an answer, seems to show that you don't appreciate and respect the time and effort of those who try to help you. You are using us, but you don't say "thank you". That is impolite.

After writing that comment, I had blacklisted your questions using a CSS custom userscript that hides your questions from me.
If you want others to interact with you online, you need to abide by the conventions of whichever website you are on. Otherwise people will stop interacting with you. On Stack Exchange sites, you show that you appreciate the time and effort that other users put into answering your questions by upvoting and accepting those answers. Whenever I ask a question, I make sure to upvote every answer I get, because I deeply appreciate that people are trying to help me.
4   You seem to be preoccupied with dysfunctional thoughts.
Many of your questions seem (to me) to result from overthinking minor and often irrelevant aspects of writing. For example, yes, cadence plays a role in both readability and pleasantness of prose, but there are other aspects that are vastly more important, such as an easy-to-parse sentence structure or an intriguing story.
If you want to write lyrical prose, you may find more resonance in a forum for writers of experimental prose or poetry. If you want to write mainstream fiction, your questions seem to be more of an obstacle to you that stands in the way of your actual writing and that you need to overcome. Instead of wondering about cadence, I recommend that you just write a lot. You'll find your style (and the answers to your questions) much more easily through practice than by theorizing.

If you aren't garbia, ignore points 3 and 4.

Please don't judge users by how many answers they have accepted or not. It's a useless metric. One that used to be on the sites but eventually was explicitly removed because of how unproductive it was. Accepting is not required. I'd even argue that accepting answers, as currently implemented, is very much against what the sites are about and does more harm than good. But that is probably a topic for another time.

@VLAZ Part 3 of my answer says: If you answer several questions posted by one user and that user neither accepts nor upvotes any of your answers, you will eventually come to feel that the person doesn't care for your answers and you will stop answering their questions. I'm not discussing how useful showing a user's acceptance rate is for the functioning of the site, so your comment is beside the point.

You're directly using the acceptance rate as a negative against a user in the quoted comment. I'm asking you to not use the acceptance rate. And it was removed from the network because of the exact manner you've used it. Therefore, I deem it was relevant to the point you were trying to make. I'm also not discussing the usefulness - 12 years ago it was already clear that it wasn't productive to display the acceptance rate. I merely informed you of this. At no point did I raise it as a question. Such a question would definitely have been besides the point.
